# Java: Showing a BoxLayout panel in the middle of the frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, boxlayout

I recently started working with Java and I am not too sure how to put my  `BoxedLayout` Panel in the middle of my `JFrame. At the moment, I have the following:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

JLabel quizLabel = new JLabel("Java Quiz",SwingConstants.CENTER);
quizLabel.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
quizLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
quizLabel.setOpaque(true);
panel.add(quizLabel);

JLabel newLineLabel = new JLabel(" ",SwingConstants.CENTER);
newLineLabel.setOpaque(true);
panel.add(newLineLabel);

JLabel createdByLabel = new JLabel("Created By",SwingConstants.CENTER);
createdByLabel.setOpaque(true);
panel.add(createdByLabel);

JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("XXX",SwingConstants.CENTER);
nameLabel.setOpaque(true);
panel.add(nameLabel);

contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

`contentPane` is taken from my frame. This gives me the following output:

[image]

I want the three labels inside the panel to appear in the middle of the Frame.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is the only panel on the screen, the BoxLayout will fill the entire frame and thus depending on how your JComponents are created in the panel, it will show it like that on the frame too.

What I would do if I were you, is created a BorderLayout as a container for your BoxLayout.

[image: This is how BorderLayour works, so for the center component your BoxLayout will fill the middle of the screen.]

This way, you can set your BoxLayout as the center of the Borderlayout. 
See if this code works:

```
//This will fill your frame
JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
contentPane.add(containerPanel);

//this is the BoxPanel you wnat your components to be organized in 
JPanel boxPanel = new JPanel(new BoxLayout());
//Add all your components to the boxPanel

//add your panel with all the components to the container panel
containerPanel.add(boxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Hey Stickerbomby thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, this is not working.Same porblem

Comment: Try adding EmptyBorders to your components to position them manually then:     JLabel createdByLabel = new JLabel("Created By")
createdByLabe.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(left,top,bottom,right));

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a GridBagLayout. Using the default constraints a single component will be centered in the panel:

```
//contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
contentPane.setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
contentPane.add(panel, new GridBagConstraints());
```